# Check whether a variable has scope at an arbitrary Source Location using clang llvm

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm-clang

I am a newbie in clang libtooling and am struggling with the following problem.

I want to perform source-to-source transformation of a given c/c++ program so that 'transformed' program prints all the 'in scope' variable values at different program points.

For Example, In the below program I want to print variable values that have scope at various SourceLocation (for example at ending of line numbered 8 and 10).  For this i need to know that variables c doesn't have scope at the end of line 8, similarly variable i and c don't have scope at the end of line 10.

Is there any API that can help finding if a variable has scope at a given SourceLocation? How do I check if a variable has scope at a particular SourceLocation in the program?

```
 1:void f(){
 2:    int a=10;
 3:    for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
 4:        if(a>10){
 5:            int b = a+20;
 6:            {
 7:                int c = b+10;
 8:            }
 9:        }
10:    }
11:}
```

The transformed program(for this example) will look like this:

```
 1:void f(){
 2:    int a=10;
 3:    for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
 4:        if(a>10){
 5:            int b = a+20;
 6:            {
 7:                int c = b+10;
 8:            };printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, i);
 9:        }
10:    };printf("%d\n", a);
11:}
```

I thought of implementing it, but a huge tool like clang should have implemented this API already!! or should be having some efficient/easy way to do this.

What is the best strategy to do this using clang-libtooling?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Clang provides an API called AST Matcher [(reference)](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html).

Compiling your code with `clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only test.c` dumps the AST.

```
`-FunctionDecl 0x3b0a750 <test_ast.cpp:1:1, line:9:1> line:1:6 f 'void (void)'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x3b51958 <col:10, line:9:1>
    |-DeclStmt 0x3b0a8c8 <line:2:3, col:13>
    | `-VarDecl 0x3b0a848 <col:3, col:11> col:7 used a 'int' cinit
    |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x3b0a8a8 <col:11> 'int' 10
    `-ForStmt 0x3b51920 <line:3:3, line:8:3>
      |-DeclStmt 0x3b0a970 <line:3:8, col:17>
      | `-VarDecl 0x3b0a8f0 <col:8, col:16> col:12 used i 'int' cinit
      |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x3b0a950 <col:16> 'int' 0
      |-<<<NULL>>>
      |-BinaryOperator 0x3b0a9e8 <col:19, col:23> '_Bool' '<'
      | |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x3b0a9d0 <col:19> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
      | | `-DeclRefExpr 0x3b0a988 <col:19> 'int' lvalue Var 0x3b0a8f0 'i' 'int'
      | `-IntegerLiteral 0x3b0a9b0 <col:23> 'int' 10
      |-UnaryOperator 0x3b0aa38 <col:27, col:28> 'int' postfix '++'
      | `-DeclRefExpr 0x3b0aa10 <col:27> 'int' lvalue Var 0x3b0a8f0 'i' 'int'
      `-CompoundStmt 0x3b51900 <col:32, line:8:3>
        `-IfStmt 0x3b518d0 <line:4:5, line:7:5>
          |-<<<NULL>>>
          |-BinaryOperator 0x3b51640 <line:4:9, col:13> '_Bool' '>'
          | |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x3b51628 <col:9> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
          | | `-DeclRefExpr 0x3b515e0 <col:9> 'int' lvalue Var 0x3b0a848 'a' 'int'
          | `-IntegerLiteral 0x3b51608 <col:13> 'int' 10
          |-CompoundStmt 0x3b518a8 <col:17, line:7:5>
          | |-DeclStmt 0x3b51760 <line:5:7, col:21>
          | | `-VarDecl 0x3b51678 <col:7, col:19> col:11 used b 'int' cinit
          | |   `-BinaryOperator 0x3b51738 <col:15, col:19> 'int' '+'
          | |     |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x3b51720 <col:15> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
          | |     | `-DeclRefExpr 0x3b516d8 <col:15> 'int' lvalue Var 0x3b0a848 'a' 'int'
          | |     `-IntegerLiteral 0x3b51700 <col:19> 'int' 20
          | `-CompoundStmt 0x3b51888 <line:6:7, col:25>
          |   `-DeclStmt 0x3b51870 <col:9, col:23>
          |     `-VarDecl 0x3b51788 <col:9, col:21> col:13 c 'int' cinit
          |       `-BinaryOperator 0x3b51848 <col:17, col:21> 'int' '+'
          |         |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x3b51830 <col:17> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
          |         | `-DeclRefExpr 0x3b517e8 <col:17> 'int' lvalue Var 0x3b51678 'b' 'int'
          |         `-IntegerLiteral 0x3b51810 <col:21> 'int' 10
          `-<<<NULL>>>
```

You can use AST Matchers to walk through the AST and match against `CompoundStmt` which will give you nodes of the AST corresponding to scopes in C/C++. From this you can start tracking all `VarDecl` to find variable declartions inside the scopes. There is no out-of-the-box solution for what you want but Clang gives you the tools to implement it.

You can also read this blog post [(link)](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/05/01/modern-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang-and-libtooling) from Eli Bendersky. He demonstrates how you can use AST Matchers and Clang's rewriting facilities to write the tool you want.